# Regexp in express get request

Tags: regex, node.js, express, get, request

I use expressjs and I want to process get request by regexp like follow

```
var app = require('express');

app.get(
    '/foo/bar/<here is  picture name e.g. test.jpg>?',
    function(req, res, next) {
        console.log('Hello');
        next();
    }
);
```

I have a problem with regexp. I want this regexp to pass all picture names even in md5 and sha1 hashes.

Comment: Use `[^\/]*(?:jpe?g|png|gif)`. Extend the nincapturing group if you need to support other extensions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a regex for this, you can use [URL parameters](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.params).

```
app.get('/foo/bar/:slug',
    function(req, res, next) {
        console.log(req.params.slug);
        next();
    }
);
```

Requesting `/foo/bar/myImage.jpg` would populate `req.params.slug` with `'myImage.jpg'`.

Comment: In that case I can pass any number as slug, but it will not be a picture name

Comment: @Mike_Device Then validate your data.